# Rendering Issues with amazon S3 bucket

Tags: css, amazon-s3

So I have a few simple static files(HTML, CSS, JS) in a S3 bucket and after a few days the files just simply stopped rendering properly. I was wondering is anyone here has an idea of what cause this or what could be causing this. I am hoping to get a faster response than amazon. 
[Render issue1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVdYM.png)

[Render issue2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM6SB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the files are declaring the content type as 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' in the metadata settings?

Comment: Yes, they have been checked and confirm.